# AWS Opsworks cannnot install and use GIT on windows Setup recipe

Tags: windows, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I'm trying to setup a windows environment within AWS Opsworks.

I have a setup recipe that will install GIT and Ruby.
And a deploy recipe that will try to use git and rake.

Setup works successfully.  However, deploy will complain that git/rake are missing.

If I reboot the instance, I can issue a deploy and git/rake will be found.

The symptoms I am experiencing are as follows:

- Start brand new instance
- Setup will properly install applications
- Deploy will fail
- Stop and Start instance
- Setup and deploy will finally succeed.

Based on my searches online, seems windows requires a reboot after changing environment variables.  Git and Ruby are added to the PATH after installation but it seems my scripts cannot locate these applications until a reboot.  I'm using opsworks_scm_checkout and powershell and both will not work.

I tried modifying my setup recipe to reboot during the startup phase, which works perfectly but my deploy application doesn't follow after the reboot.

- Start brand new instance
- Setup will properly install applications
- Reboot
- Deploy never fires, have to manually trigger this in the App Deploy

Is there a proper workaround for this?  Anyone have real life experience on how to resolve this?